# Python Attribute Error for Nearest Neighbor Classifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Getting an Attribute Error here.

I can't seem to find what's wrong with this implementation of a Nearest Neighbor classifier. Using different classifiers I've had this working great with >90% accuracy so it really must be this line 14. Any help would be greatly appreciated, trying to make sure this runs in Python 3.

Line 14:

```
label = self.closest(row)
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'DavesKNN' object has no attribute 'closest'

Full code:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def euc(a,b):
    return distance.euclidean(a,b)

class DavesKNN():
    def fit(self, X_train, y_train):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train

    def predict(self, X_test):
        predictions = []
        for row in X_test:
            label = self.closest(row)
            predictions.append(label)
        return predictions

        def closest(self, row):
            best_dist = euc(row, self.X_train[0])
            best_index = 0
            for i in range(1, len(self.X_train)):
                dist = euc(row, self.X_train[i])
                if dist < best_dist:
                    best_dist = dist
                    best_index = i
            return self.y_train[best_index]

#Import a Dataset
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# Features and Labels
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Partition Features and Labels into New Sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .5)

# from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
# my_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier()
my_classifier = DavesKNN()

my_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = my_classifier.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print (accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```

Answer (score 1):

"def closest(self, row):" was just indented when it shouldn't have been. I feel like a moron. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a 'closest' attribute for DavesKNN(). This would mean something similar to a function where, when you initialize the class, you have to pass the attribute `closest`. In the event that you are copying the DavesKNN() from somewhere else, then you need to import that.

To elaborate on how to incorporate the `closest` attribute:

You need to add a `__init__()` function at the beginning of the class, that way you can pass the attributes inside the parentheses and declare them like so:

```
def __init__(self, closest):
    self.closest = closest
```

inside the class.

Comment: It now tells me

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'closest'

Comment: Right. That's because you then have to modify the line where you initalize an object of DavesKNN() to include closest, and you have to have a closest variable